# How can I create a Delaunay mesh in set of points inside an image?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Is there a possible way to create a Delaunay mesh inside an image given a set of points inside the image? 
for instance use the pixel coordinates to create the Delaunay mesh.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/data-and-mesh-regions/create-a-mesh-region-from-image-data.html

Comment: ohh, nice, is there a way that I can extract a part of the image and compare it to another? with the mesh.

Comment: The closest thing would probably be ``ImageTrim``, which can be given a geometric region.